# How to read a file?

Tags: java, io

```
private void getInput() throws IOException {

    InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "aaa.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            resourceAsStream.toString()));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(everything);
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

The file aaa.txt is in the same project and it cannot be read, I have java.lang.NullPointerException when I execute that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Comment: In which line do you get the exception?

Comment: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
    resourceAsStream.toString())); here

Answer (score 0):

Only do this

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aaa.txt"));`

But put the file in the filereader instead.

Hope it helpt.